# Can I use jsonb_set with the new value (3rd argument) coming from a select statement?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a jsonb column and I want to migrate every record to a new schema.

Old schema: `{"foo": "bar"}`
New schema: `{"foo": {"value": "bar"}`

The `bar` value varies by row and I want to preserve that value. I need some way to lookup the value of foo from each record.

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT id AS id, col -> 'foo' AS foo
  FROM t
) UPDATE t SET col = jsonb_set('{"foo": {"value": ""}}', '{foo,value}', SELECT foo FROM data WHERE data.id = t.id);
```

I get this error with Postgres 11.21.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 4: ...jsonb_set('{"foo": {"value": ""}', '{foo,value}', SELECT foo...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a CTE, and you can move the current content without a subquery:

```
UPDATE t 
SET col = jsonb_set(col, '{foo}', jsonb_build_object('value', col->>'foo'))
WHERE id = ?; -- if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

It needed parentheses around the select:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT id AS id, col -> 'foo' AS foo
  FROM spike
) UPDATE spike SET col = jsonb_set('{"foo": {"value": ""}}', '{foo,value}', (SELECT foo FROM data WHERE data.id = spike.id))
```